# MYSQL migration and Backup automation in windows scheduler from mssql

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am planning to migrate databases from MSSQL to MYSQL. The total number of databases is 40 all together will be 60 GB in size running on express.

Would like to get your suggestion for migration to MYSQL and Backup automation in the windows scheduler after migration to MYSQL etc.

Hope I can use either mysqldump or xtrabackup.
For migration, I can use the workbench tool by ODBC connection.
Any suggestions for migration and post-task recommendations will be helpful.

Just to add, it is on windows server not in Linux.

Comment: There are lots of syntax differences.  There are lots of feature differences.  Example `TOP` versus `LIMIT` -- they provide _similar_ functionality.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames. Yes, the code level application team is reviewing it. Maybe they can plan to re-write the T-sql into mssql. I wanted to get some suggestion on DBA point of view, like easy to migrate 40 DBs and post migration steps and maintenance task automation etc in windows not in Linux